# Не могу найти ошибку в коде калькулятора

Tags: php

есть такой код, который должен рассчитывать по данным стоимость дома.
на сайте это выглядит как два селекта и поле для ввода метража. результат не выдает. не могу понять, где искать ошибку - в коде калькулятора или что-то не так на самой странице с выводом данных? подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
    <? echo $f_AdminCommon; ?>
<?php

$content = '<h1>Калькулятор</h1>';
if (isset ($_POST['material']) && isset ($_POST['type']) && isset ($_POST['metrov']))
{
$material = $_POST['material'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$metrov = $_POST['metrov'];
if($material == 'Сосна' && $type == 'Оцилиндрованное бревно') {$price = '6000';}
if($material == 'Сосна' && $type == 'Клееный брус') {$price = '11500';}
if($material == 'Сосна' && $type == 'Лафет') {$price = '8000';}
if($material == 'Кедр' && $type == 'Оцилиндрованное бревно') {$price = '8500';}
if($material == 'Кедр' && $type == 'Клееный брус') {$price = '14200';}
if($material == 'Кедр' && $type == 'Лафет') {$price = '9500';}
if($material == 'Лиственница' && $type == 'Оцилиндрованное бревно') {$price = '9000';}
if($material == 'Лиственница' && $type == 'Клееный брус') {$price = '15500';}
if($material == 'Лиственница' && $type == 'Лафет') {$price = '10500';}
}

$min_metrov = 1;
//Ошибка ввода metrov 
$error_metrov = "<p>Пожалуйста, ведите количество кв.Метров.<br>
<br>
 <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться'
onclick='javascript:history.back();' style='border:0; background-color:#455e17; color:#ffffff;'></p>
";
  ?>
<?
if(!isset ($_POST['podschet']))
{
$content .= '
<table class="calc"><tr><td>
<form name="edit_main" method="post" action="/calc/">
            <p>
              <label>Материал:<br>
                <select name="material" id="material">
                <option>Сосна</option>
                <option>Кедр</option>
                <option>Лиственница</option>
              </select>
              </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Тип сруба:<br>
                <select name="type" id="type">
                <option>Оцилиндрованное бревно</option>
                <option>Клееный брус</option>
                <option>Лафет</option>
              </select>
              </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Площадь дома (кв.м.):<br>
              <input type="text" name="metrov" maxlength="20" id="metrov">
              </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input name="podschet" type="submit" value="Расcчитать!" class="button">
            </p>
          </form>
          </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>';
}
else
{
    $tsena = $price*$metrov;    
    $fundament = $metrov*2200;
    $kommunikatsii = $metrov*3700;
    $krovlya = $metrov*2600;
    $otdelka = $metrov*8300;
    $price = $tsena+$fundament+$kommunikatsii+$krovlya+$otdelka;

    if(strlen($metrov) < $min_metrov) {
    $content .= $error_metrov;
    }
    else {
    $content .= '
    <table class="calc"><tr><td>
    <form name="edit_main" method="post" action="/calc/">
                <p>
                  <label>Материал:<br>
                    <select name="material" id="material">
                    <option '.($material == 'Сосна' ? 'selected' : '').'>Сосна</option>
                    <option '.($material == 'Кедр' ? 'selected' : '').'>Кедр</option>
                    <option '.($material == 'Лиственница' ? 'selected' : '').'>Лиственница</option>
                  </select>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Тип сруба:<br>
                    <select name="type" id="type">
                    <option '.($type == 'Оцилиндрованное бревно' ? 'selected' : '').'>Оцилиндрованное бревно</option>
                    <option '.($type == 'Клееный брус' ? 'selected' : '').'>Клееный брус</option>
                    <option '.($type == 'Лафет' ? 'selected' : '').'>Лафет</option>


              </select>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Площадь дома (кв.м.):<br>
                  <input type="text" name="metrov" maxlength="20" value="'.$metrov.'" id="metrov">
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <input name="podschet" type="submit" value="Расчитать!" class="button">
                </p>
              </form>
              </td><td>
              <h3>Материал: '.$material.'.</h3>
              <h3>Тип сруба: '.$type.'.</h3>
              <h3>Площадь дома: '.$metrov.' кв.м.</h3>
              <h3>Фундамент: '.$fundament.' руб.</h3>
              <h3>Коммуникации: '.$kommunikatsii.' руб.</h3>
              <h3>Кровля (песчано-цементная черепица BRAAS): '.$krovlya.' руб.</h3>
              <h3>Отделка: '.$otdelka.' руб.</h3>
             <h4>Итого: '.$price.' руб.</h4>

              </td></tr></table>
    ';
    }
}

print $content;

?>
```

Comment: Ну во-первых, делай проверку не на истину, а на ложь, а то у тебя громоздко получается. Во-вторых, объявляй переменные вне условий, чтобы читабельно было. Что показывает на странице после выполнения кода? То есть чего именно нет?

Comment: Месье знает про отладчик?)

Comment: Не выдает ничего - это показывает пустую страницу? Если так, то ошибка где-то в коде, смотрите логи веб-сервера.

Comment: попробуйте использовать массивы

Comment: включите отображение ошибок, попробуйте поставлять exit('point!'); в разных местах кода, чтобы найти место, до которого код выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

у тебя форма отправляется по относительной ссылке /calc/ а сам обработчик на той же странице, т.е. в двух местах удали ссылку на страницу обработчика и у тебя всё заработает, ну или обработчик вынеси на эту страницу. Также проверку полей сделай